# Swift - Error during simple Segue between TableViewController -> ViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I am attempting to pass two string values containing the values of a "Bar Name" and its respective "Street Name" using a segue between a TableViewController and a ViewController. I am using a class called `HomeController` and another called `BarPage`. I have the following code prepared for the home screen, which is a Table View Controller holding cells, which when clicked, should perform the segue I have included on the story board. I have deleted some code which would be redundant to explain this problem :

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class HomeController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

    let barsArray = [Data(image: "bar1", street: "123 North Street"),
                    Data(image: "bar2", street: "345 South Street"),
                    Data(image: "bar3", street: "678 West Street")]

    let tableView: UITableView = {
        let tv = UITableView()
        tv.separatorStyle = .none
        tv.allowsSelection = true
        return tv
    }()

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return barsArray.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
    }
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! BarCell

        cell.barImageView.image = UIImage(named: barsArray[indexPath.item].image!)
        cell.barCoverLabel.text = "Street: " + barsArray[indexPath.item].street!

        return cell
    }

    var locationName : String?
    var locationStreet : String?

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let barPage = segue.destination as! BarPage
        barPage.barName = locationName!
        barPage.barStreet = locationStreet!
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


        locationName = self.barsArray[indexPath.row].image
        locationStreet = self.barsArray[indexPath.row].street


        // WHEN USER PRESSES A ROW, PERFORM SEGUE

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "mySegue", sender: self)

        // Then enter the second view controller

        present(BarPage(), animated: true, completion: nil)


    }



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.backgroundColor = .black
        setUpTableView()

    }
    func setUpTableView(){
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.register(BarCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

        view.addSubview(tableView)

        .... add anchors and constraints for table view ..........
    }

}

var home: HomeController?

class BarCell: UITableViewCell{


    ... add custom styling for each cell of the table view ....

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?){
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        setup()
    }

    func setup(){
        .......... add anchors and constraints for the cell..........
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Here is the code from the View Controller `BarPage` that should be retrieving the Strings from his segue.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase



class BarPage: UIViewController{

    let homeController = HomeController()

    // These, in theory, should be the variables that retrieve the strings through my segue

    var barName = String()
    var barStreet = String()

    public let barStreet: UILabel = {
        var label = UILabel()
        label.text = "The street is: "// + barStreet
        label.textColor = .black
        label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
        return label
    }()
    let barImage: UIImageView = {
        let iv = UIImageView()
        iv.image = UIImage(named: barName) // Should retrieve the image based on the string that is passed
        iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        iv.backgroundColor = .yellow
        //iv.clipsToBounds = true
        return iv
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.mint()

        view.addSubview(barStreet)
        view.addSubview(barImage)

        positionElements()

    }

    func positionElements(){
        .......... add anchors and constraints for the elements..........
    }
}
```

If I run my code without including the segue, the transition works just fine. However, if I include the Segue, I get the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: 'Receiver (<ProjectName.HomeController: 0x7f9fcec0fb10>) has 
no segue with identifier 'mySegue''
```

How could this be possible if I do in fact have a segue in my story board with that identifier? Here is a picture of my story board which shows the identifier I am using:

[image]

As you can see on the right, the same identifier matches up for the segue in my story board, yet my error states that it can not be found. How can I fix this problem? Is this occurring because I am attempting to perform a Segue from a TableViewController? Apologies for any ambiguity, first month into being a Swift user. Any tips/advice that would point me in the right direction would be extremely helpful.

Comment: You perform a `segue` and then you are presenting a (different) instance of  `BarPage` manually. You can't use both simultaneously. And since you are using storyboard anyway why do you create the table view in code?  Is it particularly cool? And consider that the instance `HomeController()` is **not** the instance in the storyboard.

Comment: @vadian I created the whole table view programmatically, and have seen no way to perform a segue without implementing the story board. That is why I have included the two View Controllers detailed int he picture above. Could you please clarify by what you mean that the "instance HomeController() is not the instance in the storyboard" ? Apologies, very unfamiliar with story boards.

Comment: The default initializer `()` of a view controller creates a new blank instance of the controller which is not related to the instance in the storyboard. If you want to refer to the instance in the storyboard you need to pass the reference through the segue. If you are a beginner look for tutorials which design the UI in the storyboard. It much more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)  {
                performSegue(withIdentifier: "mySegue", sender: indexPath.row)
            }
```

Comment: Great suggestion, but the same error is still occurring @Khawar Islam

Comment: Can you please share the project.

Comment: Why you do not use Storyboard for design purposes?

Comment: I just chose to create the whole project programmatically, due to the tutorials I have been following. Is there any other way I could answer additional questions without sharing my whole project? Contains some private material.

Comment: No problem Man! I am here to help you. First Make a tableView with cell.

Answer (score 0):

Add something like this to your prepare for segue:

```
    if let selectedIndex = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        barPage.barStreet = barsArray[selectedIndex.row].street
        ...
```

}

and make sure you are calling self.performSegue...